# Specify Eclipse Version for running a Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Currently I started to work again with the development of an Eclipse plugin using Eclipse Oxygen 3a. If I run the plugin, it uses Eclipse Oxygen version 1a from fall last year. This is the last time I worked with the project. Even if I recreate the run configuration it stays the same. How can I specify the version Eclipse uses for running the plugin? I would like to test the plugin in the current version of Eclipse. I searched in the project preferences as well as in the settings of Eclipse itself and was unsuccessful.

Has anybody an idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Target Platform' specifies what is used.

Look in the 'Preferences' in 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform' to see what is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There I only have "Running Platform (Active)". The location that is shown there also points to my current Eclipse Oxygen 3a. I try to create a new platform there with the same path and see if this changes anything.

Comment: How do you know it is running Oxygen.1a?

Comment: If I run the plugin it starts a separate Eclipse instance showing the splash screen with version 1a. If I go to the about view, there it also says, that it is version 1a.

Comment: I fixed it by creating a new default target for the running platform using the add button. I do not know what was wrong with the old target, but now it works. Thanks!